# Call Service With Options In Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-framework3, zend-servicemanager

In ZF3, I am calling a form factory from a controller using this notation:

```
    $form = $this->formManager->get(myForm::class);
```

not

```
    $form = new myForm();
```

In the factory, I'm using what ZF3 recommends for the method:

```
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
       //...
    }
```

I assume that the `$options` array is intended for passing parameters to the function.  How do I populate the `$options` array in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `FormManager` above also child of `ServiceManager`. So, instead of using `get()` like this

```
$form = $this->formManager->get(myForm::class);
```

I think you can use `build()`. Here the example

```
$form = $this->formManager->build(myForm::class, $options);
```

And the options should be passed in the form factory

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    return MyForm($options);
}
```